# Integrate a 2-dimensinal function with dependencies on both conditions

Tags: integration, functions

I want to integrate the function

$f(x,y)=0$ for $x<y$ and $f(x,y)=1$ for $y>=x$

But I have a problem in doing this as it has two branches, and both of the conditions are dependant from the input parameters $x$ and $y$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x,y)=0$ for $x<y$, only integrate in the region where $y\geq x$.

Also, since $f(x,y)=1$ for $y\geq x$, the integral is simply equal to the area of the region where $y \geq x$.